# Is it redundant for a class to both extend MouseAdapter and implement MouseMotionListener?

Tags: java, extends, implements

From Java How To Program Deitel book:

> Create a single inner class that both extends MouseAdapter and
>   implements MouseMotionListener to handle all mouse events in one
>   class.

According to Java API, MouseAdapter already implements MouseMotionListener. So wouldn't it be redundant to have a class like the following?

```
private class MyEventHandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener
{
      // class code here
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is redundant. Someone might think it is making their code clearer (for some reason), but it is not required for the code.

Comment: It’s redundant for an API like this, that you can safely assume to be stable. Of course, if `MouseAdapter` was changed after compiling your program to not implement `MouseMotionListener` anymore, it made a difference.